# MYSQL PHP Select data from two independent tables for search

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery-ui, search

I have built a search using PHP, MySQL and Jquery. I am currently using two search boxes for selecting data from two independent tables.

In the first table I have details about monks. I am using the following MySQL query to fetch records:

```
SELECT * FROM munishri, upadhis WHERE (name LIKE ? OR uname LIKE ? OR prefix LIKE ? OR suffix LIKE ? OR alias LIKE ? ) AND upadhi=uid ORDER BY upadhi, name
```

In the second table I have records about temples and I am using the following query to fetch its records:

```
SELECT * FROM temples WHERE tname LIKE ? OR tadd LIKE ?
```

This type of search is good for individual pages, but not for the module on the top of website. Is there any way to display results from both the independent tables in a single textbox without making the user to pick the table? Just like a simple search fetches records from various places.

Edit:

The top search module currently is being run by jquery using the code below

```
$(function(){
    $("#search").autocomplete({
        //autoFocus: true,
        source: "search/munis.php",
        select: function (event, ui) {
            window.location = ui.item.url;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This question is way too vague. It's not clear what you're asking or what is not working.

Comment: Tonput it simply, How to show results from 2 sources for a single query?

Comment: Simple answer: use a join query.

Comment: There's no common field. One table is about people having elements like their name, date of birth, etc while other is about buildings, their address, etc

Comment: I refer you back to my first comment. Need more information to understand whats going on. You will need to help me to help you.

Comment: The website is http://jainmunilocator.org and pages are http://jainmunilocator.org/munis.php and http://jainmunilocator.org/temples/ In these two pages, the main content is a textbox which fetch the result from two distinct tables of the database. But the search on top currently fetched from munis table only. I want to add temples table results in top search too.

Comment: Ok, so if someone enters a search term, say "Kunjuvan Jain" for example, you want your PHP Script to search for this term in 2 different tables at the same time? And supply results, but both tables have no common columns?

Comment: Yes, exactly. For another example, if someone searches for say Mahavir, it scrolls through both tables and return the results. It is less likely that both tables will have value for the search term simultaneously, but it's possibility could not be ruled out.

Comment: Without a more complete example, I can only suggest you perform 2 queries in your PHP for each table, collect the results into one array, and return them to your AJAX call as 1 JSON object.